# How to install specific version in ARCH using yay?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-devcontainer, arch

I have issue with latest version of vscode==1.75.1.
I'm ussing Microsoft Dev Containers extension, and inside dev container I cannot run termminal .
[image]

Error is: The connection to the terminal's pty host process is unresponsive, the terminals may stop working.

I'm traying to find any olution for this problem.
I done uninstall, remove all filles related to vscode, install agan with yay -S visual-studio-code-bin and still have issue.

I want to install specific version of visual-studio-code-bin==1.74.3, how to install with yay -S?

p.s. This was after I updated system.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know it is not possible with yay, unfortunately.

But: why don't you try pacman?

```bash
sudo pacman -S code
```